# how to truncate words with jquery without cutting words in source code?

Tags: jquery

It is possible to truncate words or show shortened words but when reviewing the source code, show all words.

**Example:** (truncate words or shorten words.)

> testing with so...

When you inspect the source code with the developer browser tool that shows the following:

[image]

**My code**

```js
String.prototype.truncString = function(max, add){
   add = add || '...';
   return (this.length > max ? this.substring(0,max)+add : this);
};

str = "testing with some string see console output";
console.log(  str.truncString(15,'...')  );

$(function() {
 $('#original').text(str);
 $('#result').text(str.truncString(15,'...'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='original'></div>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: why not pass the whole string to a variable before you truncate it.. then just print that variable?

Comment: just print the str variable?

Comment: I misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> expected result:
>
> ```
> <div id="result">
>     testing with some...
>     <div id="original" style="display:none;"'>string see console output</div>
> </div>
> ```

Try it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="original">string see console output</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var maxlength = 10;
    var hello = $('#original').text().substring(0,maxlength)+'...';
    $('#original').before('<div id="result">'+hello+'</div>')
    $('#original').css('display','none').appendTo('#result');
});
```

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/msL6hqpr/4/**

## UPDATE 1:

I want `#original` content only the rest ("console output"):

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/msL6hqpr/5/**

## UPDATE 2:

please don't truncate complete word:

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/msL6hqpr/6/**

Comment: maybe you just have to remove CSS for `width` '-') updated with fiddle

Comment: @J.Doe if use javascript/jquery, that would be a DOM modification and affect to source structure too. just not possible, I think.

Comment: @J.Doe I see, if that what you want, I have an idea about that. I'll update my answer ... again.

Comment: @J.Doe I've fixed my answer with fiddle, you can set in `var maxlength = 10;`

Comment: @J.Doe please don't hesitate to ask. I assume this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/msL6hqpr/6/ if yes, mark my answer as approved answer :-)

Comment: @J.Doe of course you can't have two or more elements with same `id`, but you can give them the same `class` name. then you can use jQuery `.each()` function.

Comment: @J.Doe I have checked & fixed it, please check https://jsfiddle.net/qdqasyyj/2/ ... and about `.each()` you can read https://api.jquery.com/each/ to learn how to do it, because that is another problem that out of the topic from your question you've posted.

Comment: @J.Doe don't be lazy, friend :-) it's easy to learn, there are lot of examples at jquery documentation and you can copy-paste from there. this is just as simple as looping logic, you say you know PHP, then there is `foreach`, you should know it.

Comment: @J.Doe `"I will not bother you any more"` you have said that same sentence once before, lol. :D as I said, that out of the topic from the explanation you've posted. why not post a new question? then (maybe) I'll answer it (if I found it) :)

Comment: @J.Doe this question is answered & it's done, okay? I'll not go here again.

Comment: I tell a friend to ask for me about this issue is difficult to ask questions acaptadas by the community to me I was blocked I can not ask any more questions, the questions is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697355/error-in-shortening-multiple-items-with-the-same-id

Comment: In case you like to give an answer, regards @TaufikNurRahmanda

Answer (score 0):

Very simple without using jquery. Just CSS:

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Note: if you really love jquery, you can inject the proper classes dynamically using it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var str = $( "#original" ).text()
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
$( "#original" ).text(res);
```